# Admin menu issue with the modules tab

Tags: 7

I am using drupal 7, and i have a problem with the modules.The problem is when I login as an administrator i cant enter to the modules tab in the admin menu. there is a message say "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."
how can i enable a specific module?and how i fix this issue?

Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

[500 Internal server error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) is normally at Server level. To fix this, you'll first need to check is the actual error which you can check either **Drupal Logs** (located at "Admin => Reports => Recent Log message") or **Apache error log** (located at "/var/log" in Linux OS).

Comment: the drupal logs says the following: type: php Message: Trying to get property of non-object in _drupal_session_write() user:Anonymous (not verified)

Comment: Seems something is overwriting $user Object. Do you've any custom module written, which might be causing this issue. Check [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2071809) similar issue.

Comment: but sometimes the page open!

Comment: it seems that's not the problem, I give access to all the user to enter to the module page and not work. where i can check the Apache error log in the server ?

Comment: You'll need to debug a little more as `Trying to get property of non-object in _drupal_session_write() user:Anonymous` is what causing this issue. You can try doing [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) inside `_drupal_session_write()` function to see which all functions has been called before this, which will help you identify which function is playing with $user object.

Comment: Dear I call the function var_dump(debug_backtrace()); inside the _drupal_session_write(). how can i know which function is call before it ?